# variable selection and model selection

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a disease dataset, for this dataset. 
disease_rate is the dependant variable, and rest independant's.

```
data <- read.csv("H:/uni/MS_DS/disease.csv")
data

> data
         radius      texture perimeter   area smoothness desease_rate
1  -0.018743998  0.002521470 -0.005025 0.0710 0.00000000         0.07
2  -0.027940652  0.003164681 -0.004625 0.0706 0.06476967         0.02
3   0.002615946  0.001328688 -0.005525 0.0726 0.06268457         0.07
4   0.041963329  0.002769471 -0.004325 0.0699 0.06013138         0.06
5   0.030261380  0.005725780 -0.003525 0.0695 0.05942403         0.04
6  -0.030559594  0.001576348 -0.002525 0.0695 0.06110087         0.05
7   0.002698690 -0.003028856 -0.006025 0.0706 0.06207810         0.07
8  -0.044996901  0.000617110 -0.009525 0.0691 0.05940039         0.05
9   0.022993350 -0.000637109 -0.015425 0.0695 0.05870643         0.03
10  0.001398530 -0.000470057 -0.017125 0.0705 0.05540871         0.01
11  0.026827990  0.000509490 -0.014025 0.0681 0.05588225         0.06
12 -0.076220726  0.001018820 -0.010225 0.0631 0.05515852         0.01
13 -0.021917789  0.000822517 -0.003925 0.0576 0.05584590         0.03
14  0.012491060 -0.007363090  0.005175 0.0569 0.05120000         0.03
15  0.038281834 -0.008005798  0.014975 0.0576 0.04940000         0.06
16 -0.033198384  0.000350052  0.022875 0.0564 0.04930000         0.01
17 -0.002358179  0.003846831  0.022675 0.0572 0.05050000         0.07
18  0.020808766  0.000536629  0.024575 0.0656 0.04820000         0.04
19  0.091888897 -0.002393641  0.009775 0.0761 0.04740000         0.07
20 -0.036293550 -0.002889337  0.001775 0.0828 0.04770000         0.01

#Multiple Linear Model - fitting the model. 
multilinearmodel = lm(desease_rate ~ radius + texture + perimeter + area +                                 
smoothness, data = df1)
summary(multilinearmodel)

Call:
lm(formula = desease_rate ~ radius + texture + perimeter + area + 
    smoothness, data = df1)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.032172 -0.013960 -0.004256  0.013622  0.033051 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  0.06616    0.06155   1.075   0.3006  
radius       0.33809    0.14270   2.369   0.0327 *
texture      1.16524    1.54157   0.756   0.4623  
perimeter   -0.02464    0.46819  -0.053   0.9588  
area        -0.06218    0.82411  -0.075   0.9409  
smoothness  -0.36014    0.38102  -0.945   0.3606  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.0219 on 14 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3298,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.09049 
F-statistic: 1.378 on 5 and 14 DF,  p-value: 0.2909

> #Anova test.  
> anova(multilinearmodel)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: desease_rate
           Df    Sum Sq    Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
radius      1 0.0026031 0.00260313  5.4272 0.03531 *
texture     1 0.0002587 0.00025868  0.5393 0.47484  
perimeter   1 0.0000134 0.00001340  0.0279 0.86964  
area        1 0.0000012 0.00000118  0.0025 0.96109  
smoothness  1 0.0004285 0.00042853  0.8934 0.36058  
Residuals  14 0.0067151 0.00047965                  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

> # AIC
> AIC(multilinearmodel)
[1] -89.2251

> # BIC
> BIC(multilinearmodel)
[1] -82.25498
```

here only radius had a p value - P <= 0.05, rest all other variable has p value greater that radius.

is there any way to do the variable selection in such situation? cause rest all other variable has greater p value.

If there's any we can do for variable selection, please suggest. Also please help me to extract Mallows CP value for this model.

please help.

Comment: From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mallows%27s_Cp): *Mallows's Cp has been shown to be equivalent to Akaike information criterion in the special case of Gaussian linear regression.* Are you looking for `help("step")`?

Comment: @ Rui, thanks for the info, what do you think about the variable selection and model selection in the above situations.

Comment: Though there are two answers to the question [Variable selection methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099840/variable-selection-methods), I believe that this is better reposted to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable and model selection largely depends on the purpose of your model. As for general rules, the following generalisations can be helpful to keep in mind:

- Keep variables that are both quantitatively meaningful and statistically significant. You correctly identify that radius is statistically significant. It is also quantitatively meaningful (we can see this because its coefficient, 0.33809, is not ≈ 0) - so you would definitely keep this variable.
- Use judgement as to whether to retain or omit regressors that are quantitatively meaningful but not statistically significant. These variables will depend on the purpose of the model - is accuracy most important? Do you want to avoid a certain outcome (e.g. under predicting, false-positives etc etc). 'texture', and to a lessor extent, 'smoothness', both have high coefficients but also high p-values so they fall into this category. Try running models with and without them, and inspect the results. Also, if your dataset is small, try thinking about whether there is a known dependency - if there is, you may wish to keep those variables in the model
- When regressors have both poor statistical significance (i.e. high p-values) and small coefficients (like 'perimeter' and 'area') they are usually omitted from the model

To get Mallow's Cp:

```
fit <- lm(formula = desease_rate ~ radius + texture + perimeter + area + smoothness, data = df1)
library(locfit)
cp(fit)
```

You can see the documentation [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/locfit/locfit.pdf#page=11).

Find Mallow's Cp for each model you make - lower Mallow's Cp indicates a more precise model

Comment: hi user, is there a automated process of variable selection, i have writted a small code for varaible selection, but dont know how to proceed further.

Comment: library(leaps)
    library(MASS)

    model <- regsubsets(desease_rate ~  radius + texture + perimeter + area + smoothness, data = df1, nbest = 1, method = "forward",  
    nvmax =4 )       summary(model)